# Travel.SE design support request

Tags: support, design

A while back [@Jin showed us new designs for the promotion of Travel.SE](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/832/design-for-travel-stack-exchange).  We've not heard from him in a while. Any chance of an update of where we're at - it's been three months and we're excited about getting promoted!

Comment: In addition to what Mark says, I'd be more interested to know about Travel-SE progress towards graduating. We haven't heard anything from SE staff for quite some time and this has caused some uneasiness. We've got the [site stats](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6591/travel), but those are hardly indicative. Are we on the right track? What do we need to work on? Is graduating even in the works? I'm sure the community would appreciate some authoritative answers.

Comment: Well it was going to come WITH the new site design, according to Jin on the [question I linked to about the design](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/832/design-for-travel-stack-exchange)

Comment: It seems that we are ignored.... :(

Comment: Travel's still on track to graduate. We've got a few more design issues to iron out, far as I know. I'll ping Jin and ask him to give a bit more details on the state of things there.

Answer (score 11):

I apologize for the delay on this, sincerely! I was working on some design tweaks on the ones I presented, then I was occupied on other projects and had a family emergency. I'm still aiming to launch Travel.se within two weeks. I'll present an updated design in a week or so. Thank you for your patience!

Comment: Any news on that?

Comment: @Jin - how goes it? :)

Comment: @MarkMayo Jin's idea of a 2 weeks is [more like a year](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1867/make-the-mothership-shoot-its-lasers-on-hover#comment4762_1867).

Comment: 2 weeks? Not [6 to 8 weeks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/38765)?