# Repeated Travel.SE design update request please?

Tags: support, design

Back in August,  @Jin showed us new designs for the promotion of Travel.SE. We hadn't heard from him in a while. We [posted a question then](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/998/travel-se-design-support-request) back in November last year, at which Jin replied that:

> I'm still aiming to launch
>   Travel.se within two weeks. I'll present an updated design in a week
>   or so. Thank you for your patience!

However...it's now 2013, and we've not heard anything, despite some pings? Any chance of a firm update?  We've been in beta for a year and a half, with hard work, but we don't hear anything. Our understanding was that Mathematica and Travel had both been slated for promotion, and indeed, Mathematica did almost immediately back then, but we've been floating in the void ever since.

I know I speak on behalf of many members of the community when I say it would be great to get some feedback - either on the promotion, or to know where we're at, and what's happening next.  It's frustrating hearing nothing back - we'd understand a delay, but would like to know!  We've got a lot more traffic than other sites had, we're sitting well on most statistics, with a good community, and would like to see us move forward.

On behalf of the community, many thanks, look forward to hearing!

Comment: +1 - Hear, hear!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

And we've gone live! Wahey!

Thanks to the SE team, @Jin, the other moderators, and the entire beta community!