# Can the travel icon be changed to have only one single point

Tags: discussion, design

The icon for the site looks very confusing.  Everytime I see it I think of a [chicken or something with a beak](https://www.google.com/search?q=chicken%20head&safe=off&rlz=1C1RXDB_enUS591US591&espv=2&biw=1920&bih=951&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAWoVChMIuO6Kqar8xwIVCcAUCh3HNwaq).  Many times on the left side of the stack exchange sites I'll see a "hot network question" and if it comes from this site it almost looks like I am clicking a link to learn about how to cook chickens.

Can the site's logo be changed such that you have one pin point rather than the three that are currently out there?

[image]

Could be changed to indicate just one point:

[image]**Travel**

Or even maybe if the icon could be played with such that the colors are changed and the positioning of the points are changed.  It seriously looks like a [chicken with its beak open](http://s263.photobucket.com/user/ksane/media/beak.jpg.html)!

Comment: I actually quite like this logo and I'm not convinced the logo must be immediately recognisable as travel related. Looking through the hot list, very few of the site logos will immediately make clear what site they are referring to unless you know it, so for unknown sites I'd always hover over the link at it will show the name of the site.

Comment: Very nice artwork.  The gradient and shadow effect is trendy and probably took a lot of work. I'm a PovRay aficionado and appreciate the effort.  It calls to mind a locator pin.  I like it.  It works for me.  I don't know the politics involved in adopting a new logo, but I wish you all the best of luck.

Comment: I thought it was a rocket ship until just now.

Answer (score 6):

In case it's not clear, it's meant to be three points of a compass ;)

It went through a massive design process (months) with the Stackexchange team.  The final design was posted about [back then, with an explanation](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/travel-se-design-round-2?rq=1)

At the time, I agreed, it looked like a rocket ship, not a compass.  However, personally I've now grown to like the little guy ;)

Comment: Massive design process and this is what came out of it?  I still think it's very misleading and looks like the head of a chicken.

Comment: @JonH well by massive I meant drawn-out ;) I'm not on the team that did it, but you can look through that post and others like it to see who, why, and what.

Comment: I read that post and it appears I am not the only one who thinks its not a great logo or representation of the site.  The comments and even answers seem inline with what I have asked above.  Hopefully they will rethink it.

Comment: Well they didn't then, after all our comments, so it seems unlikely now :/  Also you might want to add the 'support' or 'bug' tags to your question i you want staff to see it :/

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=puffin&espv=2&biw=1379&bih=852&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAWoVChMIlPvUydv_xwIVA7waCh1_BQGN