# What is the logo?

Tags: support

Every time I see a question on the hot topics list belonging to Travel SE, I've always figured that it was a rocket to represent travel. Now when I look closer, it seems to also be some map markers. Which is it? Is it meant to be both at the same time?

Comment: Ok. That's it. **It's a Rocket!** Much cooler than map thingies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Map markers. Like a compass. Based on the 'pushpin' style on google maps and other map sites.

Originally this was the proposed design: [Design for Travel Stack Exchange](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/832/design-for-travel-stack-exchange)

Then it finalised at  this:

[Travel SE Design Round 2](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/travel-se-design-round-2?noredirect=1&lq=1)